# React-native crashes on device; Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT)

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native, android-8.0-oreo

I was creating an react-native application, I tried to get a release build, then app crashed without even starting. Then I tried upgrading react-native version, removing some packages etc. None of them worked. Application does not start on build release. Same thing started to happen when running `react-native run-android`. Application works correctly on emulator though. I have two general mobile GM5plus android 8.0 phones which I tried to run my application. I don't have any other device to test. But It used to work.

At last, I created a new project with `react-native init AwesomeProject`. Same thing happened again. All I can get from android logcat is given below. I couldn't add the whole logs. But important parts are:

```
I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.google.android.webview version 64.0.3282.137 (code 328213700)
E/linker: normalize_path - invalid input: "null", the input path should be absolute
W/linker: Warning: unable to normalize "null"
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:504] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: GetStringUTFChars received NULL jstring
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]     in call to GetStringUTFChars
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]     from int android.webkit.WebViewFactory.nativeLoadWithRelroFile(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.ClassLoader)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504] "mqt_native_modules" prio=5 tid=28 Runnable
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x12f007d8 self=0x94b7b000
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   | sysTid=9062 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x92df5970
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   | state=R schedstat=( 655088337 6798017 170 ) utm=61 stm=4 core=3 HZ=100
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   | stack=0x92cf3000-0x92cf5000 stackSize=1038KB
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #00 pc 002c42f7  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art15DumpNativeStackERNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEEEEiP12BacktraceMapPKcPNS_9ArtMethodEPv+130)
    ...
java_vm_ext.cc:504]   native: #12 pc 0063e8d5  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (Java_android_webkit_WebViewFactory_nativeLoadWithRelroFile__Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_ClassLoader_2+212)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.nativeLoadWithRelroFile(Native method)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.loadNativeLibrary(WebViewFactory.java:705)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProviderClass(WebViewFactory.java:412)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider(WebViewFactory.java:211)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   - locked <0x0a37d143> (a java.lang.Object)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance(CookieManager.java:39)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at com.facebook.react.modules.network.ForwardingCookieHandler.getCookieManager(ForwardingCookieHandler.java:181)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at com.facebook.react.modules.network.ForwardingCookieHandler.get(ForwardingCookieHandler.java:59)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at com.facebook.react.modules.websocket.WebSocketModule.getCookie(WebSocketModule.java:378)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at com.facebook.react.modules.websocket.WebSocketModule.connect(WebSocketModule.java:95)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native method)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:158)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native method)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:232)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
    java_vm_ext.cc:504] 
A/zygote: runtime.cc:492] Runtime aborting...
    runtime.cc:492] Aborting thread:
    runtime.cc:492] "mqt_native_modules" prio=5 tid=28 Native
    runtime.cc:492]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x12f007d8 self=0x94b7b000
    runtime.cc:492]   | sysTid=9062 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x92df5970
    runtime.cc:492]   | state=R schedstat=( 689958805 6798017 175 ) utm=62 stm=6 core=3 HZ=100
    runtime.cc:492]   | stack=0x92cf3000-0x92cf5000 stackSize=1038KB
    runtime.cc:492]   | held mutexes= "abort lock"
...
runtime.cc:492]   native: #17 pc 0063e8d5  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (???)
    runtime.cc:492]   at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.nativeLoadWithRelroFile(Native method)
    runtime.cc:492]   at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.loadNativeLibrary(WebViewFactory.java:705)
    runtime.cc:492]   at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProviderClass(WebViewFactory.java:412)
    runtime.cc:492]   at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider(WebViewFactory.java:211)
    runtime.cc:492]   - locked <0x0a37d143> (a java.lang.Object)
    runtime.cc:492]   at android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance(CookieManager.java:39)
    runtime.cc:492]   at com.facebook.react.modules.network.ForwardingCookieHandler.getCookieManager(ForwardingCookieHandler.java:181)
    runtime.cc:492]   at com.facebook.react.modules.network.ForwardingCookieHandler.get(ForwardingCookieHandler.java:59)
    runtime.cc:492]   at com.facebook.react.modules.websocket.WebSocketModule.getCookie(WebSocketModule.java:378)
    runtime.cc:492]   at com.facebook.react.modules.websocket.WebSocketModule.connect(WebSocketModule.java:95)
    runtime.cc:492]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native method)
    runtime.cc:492]   at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
    runtime.cc:492]   at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:158)
    runtime.cc:492]   at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native method)
    runtime.cc:492]   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    runtime.cc:492]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    runtime.cc:492]   at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29)
    runtime.cc:492]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    runtime.cc:492]   at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:232)
    runtime.cc:492]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
    runtime.cc:492] Dumping all threads without appropriate locks held: thread list lock mutator lock
...
A/zygote: runtime.cc:492] "AsyncTask #4" prio=5 tid=24 TimedWaiting
    runtime.cc:492]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x12cc04f0 self=0x95ee8000
    runtime.cc:492]   | stack=0x931dd000-0x931df000 stackSize=1038KB
    runtime.cc:492]   | held mutexes=
    runtime.cc:492]   native: #00 pc 000190fc  /system/lib/libc.so (syscall+32)
    runtime.cc:492]   native: #03 pc 002c1aeb  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art7Monitor4WaitEPNS_6ThreadEPNS_6mirror6ObjectExibNS_11ThreadStateE+130)
    runtime.cc:492]   native: #04 pc 002d25cb  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3artL13Object_waitJIEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectxi+36)
    runtime.cc:492]   at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:2135)
    runtime.cc:492]   at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:467)
    runtime.cc:492]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1086)
    runtime.cc:492] 
    runtime.cc:492]   native: #05 pc 0000089d  /system/framework/arm/boot-core-oj.oat (Java_java_lang_Object_wait__JI+92)
    runtime.cc:492]   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native method)
A/zygote: runtime.cc:492]   at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:190)
    runtime.cc:492]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1087)
    runtime.cc:500] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: GetStringUTFChars received NULL jstring
    runtime.cc:500]     in call to GetStringUTFChars
    runtime.cc:500]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
    runtime.cc:500]   native: #08 pc 000d0891  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art11ScopedCheck5CheckERNS_18ScopedObjectAccessEbPKcPNS_12JniValueTypeE+604)
    runtime.cc:500]   native: #12 pc 0063e8d5  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (Java_android_webkit_WebViewFactory_nativeLoadWithRelroFile__Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_String_2Ljava_lang_ClassLoader_2+212)
    runtime.cc:500]   at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider(WebViewFactory.java:211)
    runtime.cc:500]   at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)

    --------- beginning of crash
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 9062 (mqt_native_modu)
```

I am kind of a desperate since deployment time is quite close. Thanks in advance for help and quick responses!

Answer (score 1):

If you upgraded to 0.60.X the news I have for you is that it has major breaking changes: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2019/07/03/version-60

You should install 0.58.X, which has Android 64 support and then work your way to solve the issues there.

Comment: Thank you, I will investigate these breaking changes. My react-native version is 0.59.6 though. But, I understand from your saying  "You should install 0.58.X" 0.59.X is also affected.Then, I will try downgrading 0.58.X.